# Change Sheet name dainamically in Python

Tags: python, xlwings

in my excel file I have multiple sheets and every sheet name should be the cell value of A1.
For example there is a sheet **abc** in which cell value of A1 is **xyz**, so sheet name should be changed to **xyz**.
Please advise how can I achive this.
I am trying this code-

```
import xlwings as xw
file = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\Trading.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(file)
for sheet in wb:
    sheet_name = sheet.title
    first_cell_value = str(sheet['A1'].value)
    sheet.title = first_cell_value
    print(sheet.title)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @deadshot have updated my ques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution for this :)

```
import xlwings as xw
file = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\Trading.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(file)
for sheet in wb.sheets:
    sheet.name = sheet['A1'].value
wb.save()
```